Is there a menu bar widget in Qt Design Studio?
I just installed Qt Creator and Qt Design Studio today and I can't, for the life of me, find a widget for a menu bar in Qt Design Studio.
I've used Qt before and I know there's a menu bar widget in Qt. The vast majority of search results are about Qt Creator, and the ones referring to Design Studio aren't helpful either.
Is this just an artifact of many "modern" applications being streamlined and not having menu bars, or am I missing something here?
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Qt Design Studio is intended to create QML interfaces. What you remember is the QMenuBar used in Qt Designer, which is intended for desktop programs that use QtWidgets. While there are ways to use both Qt Widgets and QML, you normally use one or the other.

Thank you for the clarification :) I'll do some research into QML and see if that would be a better option.
